# Derivative of $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to compute the derivative of 
$$\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}.$$

This question has been bugging me for some time now.

I tried using two or three methods but didn't get an answer.

Help

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1}}$ is a constant, so the derivative is zero. Do you mean $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: The derivative of a constant is zero. Did you mean $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: Thanks didnt notice that.

Comment: @RobertZ yes the questions was x instead of 1.

Comment: @moderator To JewsInMyCamp: your display name and the picture in your profile are NOT funny at all!

Comment: Your username and profile picture have been reverted to custom ones. Please be respectful and polite, this is a one-time advice.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. The $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$ is the composition of two functions: $f(g(x))$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$. Hence, by the chain rule, the derivative should be
$$f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I made a simple error when applying the chain rule.  Thank you.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Thanks, for pointing out!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Can you calculate the derivative of $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$ from this?

**Spoiler**: Using the chain rule, you should be $$\frac{1 + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}}{2 \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{x}}}$$

Comment: Yes I arrived at the same answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you define $f(y)=\sqrt{y}$ and $g(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ then you get $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}=f\circ g(x)$. Now you should be able to compute the derivative of $f$ and $g$ and using the chain rule also the derivative of $f\circ g$.

Comment: Yes I found the derivative. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the more general case
$$f(x) = (x + x^{m})^{n}.$$
The first derivative is
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= n \, (x + x^{m})^{n-1} \, \frac{d}{dx} \, (x + x^{m}) \\
&= n \, (1 + m \, x^{m-1}) \, (x + x^{m})^{n-1}.
\end{align}
When $n=m=\frac{1}{2}$ this becomes
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{4 \, x} \, \frac{1 + 2 \sqrt{x}}{1 + \sqrt{x}}.$$